# Where can I find libdecodeqr.lib?

Tags: dll, 64-bit, shared-libraries, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am creating a QR code scanner program in C++ using the library called libdecodeqr.

I downloaded all the files from https://github.com/josephholsten/libdecodeqr and I modified one of the test programs. However, I keep getting the error "unresolved external symbol". It's because I have not linked the libraries.

But **I can't find libdecodeqr.lib** anywhere! It's not included in the GitHub package and it's nowhere online!

In the instructions on the GitHub page, it says to add decodeqr.h, qrtypes.h, qrerror.h and libdecodeqr.lib to my environment. Other than the .lib file, I have added all those files to my environment.

Where can I find libdecodeqr.lib?

Also, here is the sample program I modified and am testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "C:/Users/Asish/Documents/libdecodeqr-master/libdecodeqr/decodeqr.h"
#include "C:/Users/Asish/Documents/libdecodeqr-master/libdecodeqr/qrerror.h"
#include "C:/Users/Asish/Documents/libdecodeqr-master/libdecodeqr/qrtypes.h"
#include "bitstream.h"

using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namedWindow("src", 1);
    //
    // load image
    //

    Mat src_old = imread("qrTest.png", 1);
    IplImage* src = new IplImage(src_old);

    imshow("src", src_old);

    //
    // show version info
    //
    printf("libdecodeqr version %s\n", qr_decoder_version());

    //
    // initialize
    //
    QrDecoderHandle decoder = qr_decoder_open();

    //
    // do decode using default parameter
    //
    short stat = qr_decoder_decode_image(decoder, src);
    printf("STATUS=%04x\n", stat);

    //
    // get QR code header
    //
    QrCodeHeader header;
    if (qr_decoder_get_header(decoder, &header)){
        //
        // get QR code text
        // To null terminate, a buffer size is larger than body size.
        //
        char *buf = new char[header.byte_size + 1];
        qr_decoder_get_body(decoder, (unsigned char *)buf, header.byte_size + 1);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    //
    // finalize
    //
    qr_decoder_close(decoder);

    puts("");
    puts("Hit any key to end.");
    cvWaitKey(0);

    destroyAllWindows();
    cvReleaseImage(&src);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading the source code from GitHub, which means that you also need to create a new VisualStudio C++ project to compile your own libdecodeqr.lib (or dll). This will require you also install OpenCV in your computer.